# To tell Gmail not virus

Tags: gmail

I have imported several e-mail accounts from other my domain to Gmail and received emails from Gmail Team that some mails was treated as having a virus:

> The message "bla bla bla" from bla (bla@bla.com) contained a virus or a suspicious attachment.

These e-mails are absolutely safe and useful.

How to tell Gmail to import them?